# w2ui.grid, как изменить текст шрифта?

Tags: text, color

На третий строке, у меня должен был измениться цвет текста.
А он не изменен:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>W2UI Demo: grid-2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://w2ui.com/src/w2ui-1.4.min.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w2ui.com/src/w2ui-1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="grid" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#grid').w2grid({ 
        name: 'grid', 
        columns: [                
            { field: 'fname', caption: 'Name', size: '30%' },
            { field: 'lname', caption: 'LastName', size: '70%' }
        ]
  ,records: [
        { "recid": 1, "fname": "Ivanov", "lname": "Ivan"},
        { "recid": 2, "fname": "Petrov", "lname": "Petr", "style": "background-color: #C2F5B4" },
        { "recid": 3, "fname": "Sidorov", "lname": "Sergey", "style": "color: blue" }]
    });    
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня был использован стиль - w2ui-1.5.min.css
Там был жестко задан цвет:

```css
.w2ui-grid .w2ui-grid-body table td.w2ui-grid-data {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

Убрал цвет:

```css
.w2ui-grid .w2ui-grid-body table td.w2ui-grid-data {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

И вопрос решился.